# Laravel - global navigation

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have a navigation section built from a loop of my companies model.
So the nav looks like this

@foreach ($companies as $company)

{{ link_to("company/{$company->id}/users", $company->name, ['class' => 'btn btn-xs btn-primary']) }}

@endforeach

This grabs all of the company names and id's to build the button links for each company.
this works fine on my companies view, but I also want to include this in the main layout navigation.

What is the best why to do this? I was thinking to add a function to the base controller but not sure how or what view to return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a file, you can name something like `views/partials/companies.blade.php` and add your foreach in it:

```
@foreach ($companies as $company)

    {{ link_to("company/{$company->id}/users", $company->name, ['class' => 'btn btn-xs btn-primary']) }}

@endforeach
```

Then, everywhere you need it, you just have to tell Blade to include that partial:

```
@include('partials.companies')
```

Having your data globally available for this partial would require a [View Composer](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/views#view-composers):

```
View::composer(array('your.first.view','your.second.view'), function($view)
{
    $view->with('companies', Company::all());
});
```

You can create a file to store your composers, something like `app/composers.php` and load it in your `app/start/global.php`:

```
require app_path().'/composers.php';
```

Comment: Thanks, but I get how to do that. That would not solve my issue because I have pages that do not pull in the companies model. For example I get the companies query from using $companies = Company::all(); in my companies controller. But this is not going to be available on all my other models unless I build the query for each. How can I make this query global and use it in my main layout?

Comment: Got it. Edited to provide the Laravel way of doing this too.